# Would a charge imbalance act like dark energy?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, charge, cosmological-inflation, dark-energy

I realize that there are theoretical reasons to reject the idea that the charges on electrons and protons may not be *exactly* equal and opposite; and I am not suggesting that they're not.

**Edited 12/20/18:** However, I would like to know: ***if*** there were a very, very tiny imbalance between the electron's charge and the proton's charge **(on the order of one part in $10^{36}$ or less),** would it result in a cosmic expansion that resembles the expansion attributed to dark energy?

The rationale is that all atoms would have a very slight net charge of the same sign *if* there were such an imbalance; and as a result there would be a very slight net repulsive electrostatic force between all nominally neutral atoms.  If the imbalance were small enough, atoms should still form, gravity should be sufficient to bind most (nominally neutral) matter together on most scales, and most other phenomena should be as currently observed, but it seems that at cosmological distances there might be some observable effects.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this idea works, for the simple reason that the electromagnetic and gravitational forces scale the exact same way: they are both proportional to their respective 'charge' and inverse square.

Since your idea implies most apparently neutral objects would have roughly the same charge to mass ratio (since it depends on just the electron density), if the repulsion effect were strong enough to beat gravity at cosmological scales, it would also beat gravity on everyday scales, because the ratio of the two would remain exactly the same. But we're not repelled from the Earth.

Comment: From the Newtonian perspective that seems right, but the nonlinearity of gravity in GR should change the effective charge to mass ratio at extremely long or extremely short ranges.

Comment: by the way, it would require only the teeniest amount of unbalanced charge to overwhelm gravity because the electromagnetic force is so much stronger than gravity...

Comment: A sufficiently small imbalance would make an immeasurably small difference in the emission/absorption spectra of atoms, and the interaction between an electron and a proton would be unaffected for most practical purposes.  If there were an observable effect, I would expect it to show up in cosmological observations or in the behavior of charged matter in the vicinity of black holes.  "Neutral" matter falling into black holes would give black holes a substantial charge.   E.g., a charge ratio of $rq=10^{36}$ gives a sun-sized black hole a net charge of ~$1.9x10^{38} Coulombs.

Comment: @knzhou,  here is a counter-argument to your comment.  Your argument would seem to be correct *except* for two things.  First, if matter neutrons and other neutral particles are considered to be elementary particles in their own right, having exactly zero charge.

Comment: Sorry, hit the wrong key.  Wanted to erase the comment and write this: First, I think you are considering only the interaction between an electron and a proton, not the interaction between two atoms.  Second, it seems clear that if a universe were filled with very slightly charged, mostly uniformly distributed matter, it would experience an electrostatic pressure tending to make it expand.

Comment: @S.McGrew Well... perhaps! Perhaps you can get the details to work out. If you want to get the idea evaluated seriously, rather than by some random physics student on a website (i.e. by me), you need to look up the known constraints, work out whether your idea works quantitatively, think of possible ways to test your idea, and put it into a paper. This sort of idea does have precedent, e.g. look up millicharged dark matter, which is a (very) longshot alternative to dark energy that is similar to but distinct from your idea.

Comment: Graduate students ask some of the best questions and have some of the best ideas.  And, considering questions like these is a great way for graduate students to learn how to think scientifically.  Answering the questions - and seeing answers posed by others - is an excellent way to learn how to communicate and educate.  And finally, now and then the answers and comments provide very useful perspectives that the questioner missed before posing the question.

Comment: Looked into millicharged dark matter, thanks.  Unfortunately it lacks the key factor of charge imbalance. By the way, the only mechanism I've been able to imagine thus far by which protons and electrons might have opposite but very slightly unequal charge would reverse sign for antimatter.  Not sure if that points to a possible observational test.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this idea works. Two hand-wavy reasons:

1. This would predict that everything would be repelled from everything else on cosmological scales, which isn't true. Most things are receding from us, but not everything (e.g. Andromeda is approaching the Milky Way).
2. If there was an imbalance in electric charge in galaxies, why wouldn't free electrons be attracted to galaxies and neutralize it? For this same reason, electrically-charged black holes aren't as astronomically significant as their electrically-neutral black holes.

Comment: In regards to your second point, if the Universe has a net electrical charge, there won't be enough free electrons to go around.

Comment: @Mark that assumes there's the same number of protons as electrons in the universe, which presumably might not be the case.

Comment: In regard to @Allure's first point, a very weak repulsion wouldn't prevent relative motion.  After all, Andromeda would be repelled from all directions by surrounding galaxies.  A charge surrounded (out to infinity) by other like charges should feel no net force.

Comment: @S.McGrew wouldn't that predict that there'd be a roughly equal number of redshifted and blueshifted galaxies?

Comment: @allure, why do you think so?

Comment: @S.McGrew because the same rationale would apply to every galaxy. If the repulsion from the surrounding galaxies is enough to kick Andromeda in our direction, then it should also be enough to kick other galaxies as well, making it roughly 50-50.

Comment: Galaxies have more or less random velocities, superimposed on the cosmological expansion.  Andromeda's velocity toward the Milky Way is only about 0.006 *c*.  It seems *very* unlikely that the "kick" would be strong enough to affect the relative motion of galaxies in a neighborhood.  Dark energy doesn't.

Comment: See for example Figure 9 at [https://www.researchgate.net/publication/240578161_The_Hubble_Flow_around_the_Centaurus_AM83_Galaxy_Complex/figures?lo=1]

Comment: @S.McGrew I don't understand I'm afraid. If everything is slightly charged and repelling one another, where would the galaxies go to? They have to go somewhere right? It seems as though it'll be analogous to a bag full of air for example: the air molecules repel one another by van der waal's forces, so they have a random velocity, and any individual air molecule would see half the other molecules coming at it and half going away. This isn't observed in the case of galaxies.

Comment: Within any cluster of galaxies, that is indeed what is seen.  You can verify by doing a search for "velocity distribution of galaxies in clusters".

Comment: @S.McGrew maybe, but then why would the distribution stop being random at galaxy cluster scales?

Comment: We're getting off-topic, so this is my last reply to this thread.  Galaxies within a cluster move essentially randomly with respect to each other.  Clusters move essentially randomly with respect to each other. Space between them expands.  Peering into the cosmos at a certain distance, we see a roughly Gaussian distribution of velocities centered at the velocity corresponding to the Hubble constant and the distance.  A bit of online research will provide evidence and theory.